# invalid literal for int() with base 10 for degrees

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

first time posting. I'm making a weather forecast program on spyder but I've been getting this error in an attempt to make temperature be int

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Soren\Desktop\untitled0.py", line 13, in <module>
    tempA= int(tempA)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '52°'
```

i've attempted making it into

`tempA= int(str(tempA))`

which again shows the same error, same as float(str(tempA)).

some code:

```
tempA= tempA.replace(u'\\N(DEGREE SIGN)', '')
tempA= float(tempA)
tempA= (tempA-32) * 5/9
tempA= round(tempA)
```

thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: could you show the code referenced in the error? We need more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Unicode escape uses curly braces, not parentheses:

```
tempA = tempA.replace(u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}', '')
```

Once you replace the degree sign, you can go ahead with your math or int conversion:

```
tempA = "52°"
tempA = tempA.replace('\N{DEGREE SIGN}', '')
tempA = round((float(tempA) - 32) * 5/9)
```

Comment: that worked! thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

character '°' can't become `int`.
you must bring only integer of temperature like this

```
tempA= float(tempA[:-1])
tempA= (tempA-32) * 5/9
tempA= round(tempA)
```